# UIActivityIndicatorView inside Custom Keyboard iOS 8 doesn't animate swift

Tags: swift, ios8, custom-keyboard

i'm doing a iOS 8 custom keyboard in swift, and i have add a UIActivityIndicatorView to the view, the problem is that i can see it, but doesn't rotate, it's static, this is the code:

```
@IBOutlet var menuLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.load_indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0, 50, 50)) as UIActivityIndicatorView
    self.load_indicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    self.load_indicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
    self.view.addSubview(self.load_indicator)
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.load_indicator.startAnimating()
        })
}
```

the loading indicator appears, but it's static, how i can do?

Comment: I think you don't need "dispatch_async" because viewDidAppear is already running on the main thread. But I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: without that still does not work

Answer (score 0):

```
load_indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0, 50, 50))
load_indicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
load_indicator.startAnimating()
load_indicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
view.addSubview(load_indicator)
```

You need to start the animation with

```
load_indicator.startAnimating()
```

You might also be interested in this class: https://github.com/goktugyil/CozyLoadingActivity